# EvalError when trying to load realtime data model

Tags: google-drive-api, google-chrome-app, google-drive-realtime-api

I'm trying to get realtime data model with [gapi.drive.realtime.load](https://developers.google.com/drive/realtime/reference/gapi.drive.realtime#gapi.drive.realtime.load) method in my Chrome Packaged App :

```
gapi.drive.realtime.load(fileId, onLoad)
```

but I'm caught an EvalError:

> Uncaught EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' apis.google.com drive.google.com".

Of courcse, I can just add 'unsafe-eval' to manifest, but I guess it is bad way to solve this  problem. Can you suggest better solution ?

Answer (score 2):

A packaged app can't have a less restrictive CSP than the default, so your proposed change to the manifest wouldn't have worked. Instead, create a sandboxed iframe that allows eval(), then message back and forth between the iframe and your app. [This is a good example](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/sandboxed-content) with links to further documentation.

Comment: I've changed "content_security_policy" (like this : [dev.chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html#relaxing-eval)) and it's solved the problem. But I think it's a hack, like using sandboxed iframe. Thank you for your example anyway. Looks like realtime api can't be used in packaged apps without any hacks.

Comment: @edencore It didn't work for me, I got "content_security_policy' is only allowed for extensions and legacy packaged apps, but this is a packaged app." when I added "content_security_policy" for my packaged app, I think Google has disallowed it now.